# Is there a way to get the probability from the probability density in multivariate kernel estimation?

Tags: matlab, kernel-density

I have a question about multivariate kernel density in matlab, which is my first time using it.

I have a 3-dimensional sample data (x, y, z in axes) and want to find a probability of being in a certain volume using kernel density estimation. So, I used the mvksdensity function in matlab and got the probability density (estimated function values) for the points I decided.

What I originally wanted to do was to (if I could fine the function) triple integral the multivariate function for a given volume. But the mvksdensity function only returns the density estimates and does not return the function. I thought there will be an easy way to compute the probability from the density, but I’m stuck. Does anyone have any useful information for this? Thanks in advance.

I thought about fitdist function to find the distribution, but it only works for univariate kernel distribution.

I also tried to use mvncdf, which is a function that returns the cdf of the multivariate normal distribution for the row of the sample data after setting the mean and the std. But then I have to calculate the probability for a given volume for every normal distribution in each data point and then add it, which will be inefficient for a large amount of data and I don't know if it's a correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest the following Monte-Carlo approach. You find a master volume that contains the entire mass of the estimated probability density. This should be as small as possible for the sake of efficiency. Then you generate a large number of test points in the master volume, either on a grid or randomly according to a uniform distribution. The probability content of a specific volume V can be estimated by the sum of the density values of the test points in V over the sum of the density values of all test points. I am afraid, however, that in 3D you would need at least 1E6 test points, probably more. If you give me access to your sample, I would be pleased to try out my suggestion. It should also be fairly easy to work out an estimate of the standard error of the estimated probability content of V.

Comment: I'm afraid it will be difficult for me to provide the sample, but thank you for the answer. I will try to apply it.